# Bootstrap header desktop mobile version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a header which uses the max with when viewing on a desktop and 0 padding on the mobile version. How do I get this working?

Code:

```
  <div class="row">

          <div class="span12">

          <h1> HEADER</h1>

          </div>   

  </div>

   <div class="row black">

          <div class="span1">      
          </div>   

         <div class="span2 black">      
          </div> 

         <div class="span2 grey">      
          </div> 

         <div class="span2 black">      
          </div> 

         <div class="span2 grey">      
          </div> 

         <div class="span2 black">      
          </div> 

          <div class="span1">      
          </div>                                                              

  </div>
```

Comment: how is using `max-width` on desktop excluding `padding: 0` on mobile?
i'd say: use CSS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I understand now what you want to achieve.
If you need span12 to be 100% width, use:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

instead of the fixed pixel `row` class.